# Google Cloud - Where do I need to register my app?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I don't know where I need to register my app after created my first project. I already followed their instruction regarding to app registration.

https://cloud.google.com/console

To register a new application, do the following:

1. Go to the Google Developers Console.
2. Select a project, or create a new one.
3. In the sidebar on the left, select APIs & auth. In the displayed list of APIs, make sure all the APIs you are using show a status of ON.
4. In the sidebar on the left, select Registered apps.
5. At the top of the page, select Register App.
6. Fill out the form and select Register.

Comment: Which step are you stuck in ?

Comment: Are you using new Google Developers Console / old version ?

Comment: the latest one, do you know how?

Comment: You should switch back to old version to follow the steps. The Developers Console is just updated but the instructions are not updated yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions you pasted refer to the older API Console.

You can either figure out their Cloud Console equivalents (Create Project, etc), or go to the previous version at https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect

It's worth pointing out that Google's terminology is somewhat muddled. Sometimes "app" refers to a "project", other times it refers to a "client" within that project.

For example, you might have a project called "My Multi-Device Task List". That may have a web client, an Android client and an iOS client. Sometimes the word "app" refers to the project, other times it refers to one of its clients.

Comment: can anyone give me a link to "Registered apps" ? I cannot find it anywhere.